# Text-based style transfer

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, recurrent-neural-network, generative-adversarial-network

I am struggling to find any research into text-based style transfer using GANs. What are the primary limitations of existing technology and data that are preventing progress on this topic?

An example of style transfer would be:

`Hello, how are you?`

to

`holla, how art thee?`

Comment: There is no limitation on the style transfer concept and the GAN concept. Try and explore research from different journals.

Comment: You might want to check out [this](https://github.com/fuzhenxin/Style-Transfer-in-Text) list of papers.